# Calculate the number of days between a cell and today in excel?

Tags: excel

How does one calculate the number of days between a cell with a date and today?

I've tried:

```
=B2-TODAY() 
=(B2)-TODAY()
=(B2-TODAY()).days
etc...
```

and am having no luck.  How do I get the difference between cell B2 and today, in number of days?

Comment: `=B2-TODAY()` is the correct way, if `B2` actually contains a date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first formula should work, as long as the value in B2 is a real date and not some text that looks like a date.

To test if a cell is a real date, try to change its formatting from short date to long date. Or change it to General and it should turn into a number. If it does not change, it's not a date.

edit: Format the result as GENERAL, not date. Excel uses numbers to store dates. Days are whole numbers. If you subtract two dates you want to see the result as number of days not as dates.

Comment: It's a date I think because the value `1/8/2020` changes to `43838 `when I select general formatting.  However when I try `B2-TODAY()` I get `2/6/1900` as a result?

Comment: That did it. I'm doing this with the browser version of excel and it didn't refresh properly.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following,

`DATEDIF(A2,B2,”D”)`

You can even get Months, years and year months.

Find more details here : [Date Difference Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-8235e7c9-b430-44ca-9425-46100a162f38)

Comment: I tried `=DATEDIF(B2,TODAY(),”D”)` and it's returning a #NAME? result. B2 is formatted as date, and when I change it from date (1/8/2020) to general it changes to 43838 so I think it's properly a date?